# Start systemd service after internet clock

Tags: systemd, timestamp, clock

My systemd service starts at boot, and creates a log file with timestamps.

However, as it is running in a device without real time clock (Raspberry), it writes some lines with wrong timestamps from previous boot before getting time from Internet and starting doing it correctly (4G/LTE connection takes about one minute to connect).

How should I make the service wait for correct Internet time before starting? 
I would like it to start even with wrong time after some minutes in case it cannot connect.

Answer (score 1):

According to systemd.special(8), you need to order your service `After=time-sync.target`. (There is also a similar `time-set.target` which doesn't provide an accuracy guarantee, just that the clock is roughly ok.)

It's up to the time sync daemons to correctly order themselves before time-sync.target, but you can also enable the `systemd-time-wait-sync.service` unit to wait until the kernel reports NTP synchronization.